# python code throw Exception in new environment but works fine without it

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, virtualenv, urllib2

So when I debug my code in pycharm I caught an exception in urllib2.urlopen:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
req = urllib2.Request(urlname)
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

This is an error I caught:

```
'Exception Error in Token:RequestToken : (<class
\\'urllib2.URLError\\'>, URLError(SSLError(1, u\\'[SSL:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
(_ssl.c:661)\\'),), <traceback object at 0x7fbcfbfb1a70>)'
```

I should did like this actually:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
req = urllib2.Request(urlname)
urllib2.urlopen(req, context=context)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see what the error is. [ask]

Comment: There are diffrent interpreters for your script. you can add `#!/usr/bin/python`  at the beginning of your script and it gets called by this one by default.

Comment: Nope I dont need my default Python 2.6 so I Installed 2.7 and created virtualenv Anyway I added exception error in first message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround could be:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

But it is not good anyway.